# Detect if text is highlighted on mouse up jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if any text is highlighted using jQuery.

I tried:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    if(typeof window.getSelection!="undefined"){
        console.log("text highlighted");
    }
});
```

but it dind't work, the `console.log()` fired each time the mouse click was released, even if there wasn't any highlighted..

Comment: dom events work only on DOM

Comment: so? sorry i'm not an expert, I took the highlight code from another response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    var highlightedText = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        highlightedText = window.getSelection().toString();
    } 
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        highlightedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    if(highlightedText != "")
        console.log("text highlighted.");
});
```

Comment: @PeterZelak, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    if (window.getSelection().toString() != "") {
        console.log("text highlighted :" + window.getSelection().toString());
    }
});
```

This is another way this could be done